# Delete a file and return the previous flux in the pipeline webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have a use case to process a filePart. For processing, I am saving it locally using `filePart.transferTo`. Then I create a flux from it and then I want to delete the local file created. For the same, I have the following piece of code, but it tries to delete the file while iterating the flux and it is needed only one time. I can't use `then` as the flux will not be returned. Could someone please tell the correct way for doing this?

```
class ClassA {

    FileHandlerService fileHandlerService;

    Flux<ClassB> functionA(Mono<FilePart> filePartMono) {
        fileHandlerService.saveFile(filePartMono)
        .then(filePartMono)
        .flatMap(this::getItems)
        .flatMap(item ->
            filePartMono.flatMap(
                filePart -> fileHandlerService.deleteFile(filePart))
            .then(Mono.just(item)))
    }

    Flux<ClassB> getItems(FilePart filePart) {
        // method body
    }
}
```

```
class FileHandlerService {
    public Mono<Void> saveFile(Mono<FilePart> filePartMono) {
        return filePartMono
            .flatMap(filePart ->  filePart.transferTo(Path.of(filePart.filename())));
    }

     public Mono<Void> deleteFile(FilePart filePart) {
        return Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
                    File file = new File(filePart.filename());
                    Files.deleteIfExists(file.toPath());
                }).then()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could delete the temporal file on completion:

```
    Flux<ClassB> functionA(Mono<FilePart> filePartMono) {
        return filePartMono.flatMapMany(filePart -> fileHandlerService.saveFile(filePartMono)
                        .then(filePartMono)
                        .flatMapMany(this::getItems)
                        .doOnComplete(() ->
                                filePartMono.flatMap(it -> fileHandlerService.deleteFile(it))
                                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                                        .subscribe()
                        ));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for checking this. I had some doubts, could you please check? 1) `doOnComplete` is for synchronous side-effects like logging and not for calling reactive functions right? 2) Ideally, we don't want to call `subscribe()` so that the flow is reactive throughout?